# How to read a bool using std::cin

Tags: c++, boolean, iostream, cin

I am new to C++ and I was wondering how the function cin in case of a boolean data works.
Let's say for instance :

```
bool a;
cin >> a;
```

I understand that if I give 0 or 1, my data a will be either true or false.
But what happens if I give another integer or even a string ?

I was working on the following code :

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    bool aSmile, bSmile;
    cout << "a smiling ?" << endl;
    cin >> aSmile;
    cout << "b smiling ?" << endl;
    cin >> bSmile;
    if (aSmile && bSmile == true)
        cout << "problem";
    else
        cout << "no problem";
    return 0;
}
```

If I give the values of 0 or 1 for both boolean, there is no problem.
But if I give another integer, here is the output :

```
a smiling ?
9
b smiling ?
problem
```

I am not asked to enter any value to bSmile, the line `cin >> bSmile` seems to be skipped.
The same happens if I give a string value to aSmile.

What happened?

Comment: Try cin.clear() after taking in aSmile

Comment: This code is fail() for error checking.

Comment: Relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24504582/test-whether-stringstream-operator-has-parsed-a-bad-type?noredirect=1#comment37965807_24504582

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/num_get/get):

> If the type of `v` is `bool` and `boolalpha` is not set, then if the value to be stored is ​`0​`, `false` is stored, if the value to be stored is `1`, `true` is stored, for any other value `std::ios_base::failbit` is assigned to `err` and `true` is stored.

Since you entered a value that was not `0` or `1` (or even `"true"` or `"false"`) the stream set an error bit in its stream state, preventing you from performing any further input.

`clear()` should be called before reading into `bSmile`. Also, this is a good reason why you should always check if your input suceeded with a conditional on the stream itself.

Comment: It might be worth adding that you can make the errors more obvious with exceptions: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/exceptions/

Comment: Thanks a lot. With cin.clear before the bSmile input it works for other integers, but it's still not working for strings !

Comment: @Xema "Not working" is very vague, you need to show the code and the behavior.

Comment: I just add cin.clear() after the "cin >> aSmile" in the code above. And with a string input, the result is the same as the one without cin.clear() (you can see it above)

Comment: @Xema When you say "string input" do you mean you're providing characters as input? Is `aSmile` still a `bool`?

Comment: I put "false" in aSmile (while aSmile is a boolean).

Comment: @Xema You need to enable boolean string input using `cin >> boolalpha`.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. But with cin >> boolalpha i can't use both string and integers right ? Is there a way to use them both at the same time or not ?

Comment: @Xema The only way I'd know of is to override the `std::num_get` facilities and incorporate that custom functionality. Either that or read the values into a string and parse the correct value.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, in c++, a boolean variable can take only two values, true & false.
If you want to enter the value of a boolean later in your program, you can by not initializing the variable
eg, bool isMale;

later in your program, if you want to give the boolean variable 'isMale' a value, you can do so by ..

```
cin >> isMale;
```

But then make sure the value you enter is either true or false, else the program will throw an error

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).