# while loop doesn't loop in c++

Tags: c++, loops, if-statement, while-loop

So i just started C++ yesterday, I had a fair bit of java experience so that be the cause idk,
I try to run this code and for some reason the while loop isn't looping, i tried changing the if break statement from `ask==false` to `ask=false`, that just ends up with an infinite loop without even taking user input.

Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    double raduis;
    const double pi = 3.14;
    bool ask;
    
    while(true){
        cout << "Enter the raduis of the circle:"<< endl;
        cin >> raduis;
        double circ = 2*pi*raduis;
        double area = pi*pow(raduis,2);
        cout << "The Circumference of the circle is: "<< circ <<endl;
        cout << "The Area of the circle is: "<< area<<endl;
        cout <<"Would you like to run again?"<< endl;
        cin >> ask;
        if(ask==false){
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried changing the `bool` to a `char` value with `"y"` or `"n"` values but to no avail nothing works.

Edit: Okay so I've solved the problem, as per @zdf 's suggestion I entered `cin >> boolalpha >> ask;` and it works perfectly now.

Comment: what is your input ?

Comment: Edit comment: you can use single backticks for inline code i.e. \`false\` gives `false`. The triple backtics for blocks of code need to be on a new line.

Comment: (1) Try this: `std::cin >> std::boolalpha >> ask`. You probably entered `true`. (2) You can use `if (ask)...`.

Comment: Similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26203441/cin-and-boolean-input

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Call clear on `cin` before the input and make sure the input is only `0` or `1`,

From [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/num_get/get):

> If the type of `v` is `bool` and `boolalpha` is not set, then if the value to be stored is ​`0​`, `false` is stored, if the value to be stored is `1`, `true` is stored, for any other value `std::ios_base::failbit` is assigned to `err` and `true` is stored.

Comment: Note that e.g. `Scanner` and `Boolean.parse(String)` in Java are more permissive if I'm not mistaken, so this may indeed be a problem introduced by a change of runtime.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes what ? This question is about C++ not Java

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Literally on the first line: "So i just started C++ yesterday, I had a fair bit of java experience so that be the cause idk".